# glPushMatrix and OpenGL ES

Tags: opengl-es

I have a question regarding [glPushMatrix], together with the matrix transformations, and OpenGL ES. The GLSL [guide](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GLSL_Programming/Vertex_Transformations) says that under OpenGL ES, the matrices have to be computed:

```
However, when developing applications in modern versions of OpenGL and 
OpenGL ES or in WebGL, the model matrix has to be computed.
```

and

```
In some versions of OpenGL (ES), a built-in uniform variable 
gl_ModelViewMatrix is available in the vertex shader
```

As I understood, `gl_ModelViewMatrix` is not available under *all* OpenGL ES specifications. So, are the functions like `glMatrixMode`, `glRotate`, ..., still valid there? Can I use them to calculate the model matrix? If not, how to handle those transformation matrices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: You shouldn't use the matrix manipulation functions in regular OpenGL as well. In old versions they're just to inflexible and also redundant, and in newer versions they've been removed entirely.

Second: The source you're mentioning is a Wikibook which means it's not a authorative source. In the case of this Wikibook it's been written to accomodate for all versions of GLSL, and some of them, mainly for OpenGL-2.1 have those variables.

You deal with those matrices by calculating them yourself (no, this is not slower, OpenGL's matrix stuff was not GPU accelerated) and pass them to OpenGL either by glLoadMatrix/glMultMatrix (old versions of OpenGL) or a shader uniform.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know of any Java library that would handle the transformation matrix operations?

Comment: @JakubM.: Unfortunately no, but you could use my https://github.com/datenwolf/linmath.h C "library" which covers the most important vector, matrix and quaternion operations and translate it into Java. I'm not really a Java guy I must admit, I don't feel comfortable working with it.

Comment: Thanks, that will be useful! Normally I would go pure C, but I plan to work with Android, so Java is inevitable here

Comment: By the way, you have a small bug there: you use `vec3_len` (line 42) but define `vec3_length`, same with `vec4_...`

Comment: @JakubM.: Thanks for finding this. I use this library mostly in tutorials, because it's neither meant to be optimized nor used in serious programs (thus the single header file implementation).

Comment: Hmm, another one? Identity matrix after rotation should have element `M[15] == 1` and it is `M[15]==0`. Tell me if you don't maintain the lib anymore, then I won't bother you :)

Comment: @JakubM.: Well, I actually do maintain it, if I find the time for it. ATM I'm stuck with my diploma thesis, and every now and then I can take a peek at SO and my neewsfeed, whenever some backup is running or my data analysis programs munch some data.

Comment: @JakubM.: Okay, I just fixed those two issues.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8959/discussion-between-jakub-m-and-datenwolf)

Comment: @datenwold You said matrix functions in old OpenGL versions are redundant and inflexible. I'm using OpenGL ES 1.1 in an old project, and I totally agree they're inflexible. Could you please show some references on how to replace them? What other functions can provide a similar functionality?

Comment: @VictorMaiaAldecôa: The modern way is to use a real math library for doing the matrix calculations. Then you just load the readily prepared matrices into OpenGL. In modern OpenGL as a shader uniform, in old OpenGL using glLoadMatrix. Popular libraries are GLM and Eigen. I also wrote one called linmath.h, but I no longer actively maintain it (I'll merge usefull patches though).

Answer (score 1):

If you're planning on doing this in Android, then take a look at this. 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/Matrix.html

It has functions to setup view, frustum, transformation matrices as well as some matrix operations.

Comment: Thanks! by the way, do you know if I can import this library to an application that is *not* Android, but a regular Java app? (I ask about portability, not licensing)

Comment: As long as you include the Android libraries on your Java Build Path, I don't see why not.