# How do you calculate transformation matrix for shader in OpenGL

Tags: opengl

In newer OpenGL specifications, matrix manipulation functions are removed. You need to calculate the transformation matrices by hand and pass them to the shaders. Although `glRotate`, `glScale`, etc. disappeared, I didn't see anything in exchange...

My question:

how do you handle the transformations? Do you dig the theory and implement all by hand, or use some predefined libraries? Is there any "official" OpenGL solution?

For example, [datenwolf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/524368/datenwolf) points to his hand made C library [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9715760/glpushmatrix-and-opengl-es/9716063#9716063). For Java users (Android) there is [AffineTransform](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html) class, but it applies to 3x3 matrices, so it needs an extra effort to apply it to OpenGL `mat4`

What is your solution?

Comment: -1: This is a poll question. These are not welcome on SO.

Comment: @NicolBolas: I disagree. There is a clear issue: "no OpenGL support for transformations anymore, what to do with that?". You can bash every second question saying that it is a poll.

Comment: No, you asked, "What is your solution?" That's a poll question, because *everyone* has a different solution. You're asking us individually how we deal with this.

Comment: @NicolBolas You could argue that's the case for almost every SO question  - people asking for other's solutions to their problem.

Comment: @cbamber85: Look at his post. He makes mention of two separate libraries for doing similar stuff. If he's using C, he could just use Datenwolf's library. He clearly wants a *list*, not a single, definitive answer. He provides no criteria for saying that "Eigen" would be a preferable answer to "GLM" or "TVmet" or anything else. He doesn't even state a *language*. That's not a practical, answerable question. It's "keep guessing until Jakub M. gives an accept check."

Answer (score 3):

> how do you handle the transformations? Do you dig the theory and implement all by hand, or use some predefined libraries?

Either way goes. But the thing is: In a real program that deals with 3D geometry you need those transformation matrices for a lot more than just rendering stuff. Say you have some kind of physics simulation running. The position of rigid objects is usually represented by their transformation matrix. So if doing a physics sim, you've got that transformation matrix lying around somewhere anyway, so you just use that.

In fully integrated simulation engines you'll also want to avoid redundancies, so you take some physics simulation library like ODE, Bullet or so and modify it in a way that it can work directly on your object representing structures without copying the data into library specific records for procressing and then back.

So you usually end up with some mixture. Some of the math comes in preexisting libraries, others you implement yourself.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with datenwolf, but to give an example I use [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page), which is a fantastic general purpose matrix math library.

Answer (score 0):

above glsl 3.0 the glTraslate(),glRotate(),fTransform() etc. functions are deprecated.. but still can be use.

one better way is to use some math library like GLM http://glm.g-truc.net/    which is compatible with the glsl specifications.

The projection matrix, model matrix and view matrix are passed to the shader as uniform  variables.